# How to create a custom label in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'd like to extend simple_form to create a label with some extra info, if the model provides this functionality.

So this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(example) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :age %>
<% end %>
```

should result in something like

```html
<form...>
  <div...>
    age
    <span>...</span>
  </div>
  <input...>
</form>
```

if certain condition is met (e.g. `example.age_description?`is true).

This is how it would look without simple form:

```
<form...>
  <div...>
    <%= Example.human_attribute_name(:age) %>
    <% if example.age_description? %>
      <span>...</span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <input...>
</form>
```

Providing a block to generate the label would be nice, but I don't think that's possible.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments this could work:

```rb
# some helper
def simple_input(form, model, attribute)
  
  description = tag.span ... if model.send("#{attribute}_description?")
  label = tag.div #...
  form.input attribute, label: label
end
```

```
# used in erb, within as simple_form
<%= f.text :an attribute %>
<%= simple_input f, example, :age %>
```

But the idea is to use `simple_form` itself, to simplify maintenance.

Comment: you pass the `label` option to input - check simple_form usage - https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/master/README.md#usage

Comment: @SampatBadhe indeed, creating the code in some helper and returning it with `.safe_html` to the label option will work. But this needs to be added to every single piece of code adding an input (which is a lot). This is why I'm looking for a way to extend the logic directly form simple_form, is much more easy to maintain.

Comment: I think `i18n` will work in your case. check documentation for   [simple_form#i18n](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#i18n)